# How to display a timestamp in DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS in hive

Tags: sql, hive, unix-timestamp

My data column has "2022-04-09 11:30:00" and i need to display it as "09-Apr-2022 11:30:00"

i am not familiar with unix_timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `date_format()` with desired formatted data.

```
SELECT date_format('2022-04-09 11:30:00', 'yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss')
```

[image]

Comment: For me it was displaying "06-Apr-2022 12:00:00"date format was fine.But why time was showing different

Comment: it should give proper time and shouldnt 12:00:00. I tested ib latest version of hive. can you pls check your hive version and if your timezone and server timezone are different.